# Android MediaPlayer останавливает приложение

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Доброго дня дорогие друзья!
В общем, такая проблема. Хочу реализовать воспроизведение файла *.mp3, который лежит в /raw
Код следующий:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.of);
mp.start();
```

все довольно прозрачно, но при запуске на устройстве приложение останавливается.
Пробовал запихивать в отдельный поток, всячески манипулировать, но ничего не помогает, прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Возьми код отсюда, он рабочий:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/236-urok-126-media-mediaplayer-audiovideo-pleer-osnovnye-vozmozhnosti.html

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. Пожалуйста, добавьте решение в текст ответа, а ссылку оставьте в качестве источника.